# How do I increase opacity of the image carousel?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the opacity of the client images on the website I am working on. It shows the actual opacity while hovering but there isn't any way I could change the actual active opacity. you can check the website [here](http://iccdadar.com/).

[image: screenshot of the page]

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: It's better to put your code here, but it's ok now. one question, why you wanna increase opacity? make your default opacity `.9` and for `:hover` make your picture opacity `1`. I think you already did this way.

Answer (score 0):

In the class .tt-hover you set the opacity to 0.5. In the hover pseudoclass it's set to 1. You just have to change the opacity in the default class, like this:

```
.tt-partner {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    border-top: 1px solid #e6e9ea;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e9ea;
    padding: 42px 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```